# How to set Permalinks properly in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to open my page but its not redirect properly it's seem "/" missing after .com
I checked all in the database and fix all the missing "/" but still it's not working

I install WordPress on other site and complete this website after completion I upload my website to client domain after everything It not redirect properly, I checked whole database but can't find the issue. I saw some slash missing and put "/" but still it's not working.

here is the URL of website:https://thesmarttailor.com/
when you click on services and it's redirect to: https://thesmarttailor.comshortening-and-lengthening-pant-and-dress-hems/

See "/" missing after.com

5/2

error screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GO to setting -> then goto permalinks

[image]

then save

Comment: Yes i see, go to pages, and edit pages one by one, when you edit the page, you see also permalink, edit the permalink and add the /